# How to add Textarea in address text box

Tags: html, textarea

I am trying to add textarea in a text box but I could not applied same position, How to add textarea in my code i want to add the text box below.

```
<div class="field">
 <label for="billing:telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?></label>
  <div class="input-box">
    <input type="tel" name="billing[telephone]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Telephone')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" id="billing:telephone" />
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">
    </textarea>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```css
.input-box{
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.input-box textarea {
    margin: 30px 0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="field">
            <label for="billing:telephone" class="required"><em>* Mobile Number</em></label>
            <div class="input-box">
            <input type="tel" name="billing[telephone]" value="" id="billing:telephone" placeholder="mobile number"/><br>
            <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether or not my answer would help, but why don't you try using table tag..
Here's an example..

```html
<div class ="field">
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
 <label for="billing:telephone" class="required"><p>* Mobile Number</p>
 </label>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
 <input type="tel" name="billing[telephone]" value="" id="billing telephone" placeholder="your phone number"/>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td><textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

cheer's mate..